# Driver page source not catching new page information

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am using selenium/Bs4 to return games scraped from this page, example output is below in a list format. However, I use selenium to click and change time frame parameters which results in different games appearing. When i try to use bs4 to scrape the updated driver.page_source It appears to be not capturing the new javascript, any ideas on how to update the driver page correctly here? The headless function may need to be set True to run

[{'match': 'Breidablik - Fylkir',
'time': '21:15',
'odds': [],
'bestOddsBookie': ['Unibet',
'Betfair',
'Betfair',
'Unibet',
'BetVictor',
'Interwetten',
'1xBet',
'ComeOn',
'William Hill',
'Unibet']},
**EDIT: adding a refresh to the driver page source has seemed to work.**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import warnings
from tabulate import tabulate
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep, time

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

scraped_match_names = []
scraped_match_odds = []
bookLines = []
url = f'https://www.betexplorer.com/odds-movements/soccer/'
option = Options()
option.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/paulc/Documents/PremNet/chromedriver.exe",
                          options=option)
driver.get(url)

#click the cookie pop up
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]'))).click()

# Change the hours filter to <1 hour
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/section/div[2]/ul[1]/li[2]'))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/section/div[2]/ul[1]/li[2]/div/ul/li[1]'))).click()

# change the time for next day

WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/section/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]/div/ul/li'))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/section/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]/div/ul/li[1]'))).click()

# scroll down the page
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

# extract the page source
pageSource = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML")

sleep(10)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'html.parser')

matches = soup.find_all("td", class_="table-main__tt")
```

Comment: "It appears to be not capturing the new javascript" -- what does this mean exactly?  Can you give a specific example of what the code does, and what you expected to happen istead?

Comment: so if you were to open that url it displays information pertaining to games, with the filter on last 12 hours and next 7 days. Previously, If i were to use soup to scrape the html content it will display the static info on the page. When i use selenium to change the parameters of the two above conditions the info on the page will change but it wont be captured in page_source

Comment: The page source should be available simply as `driver.page_source`.  Why are you using a script to do that?  I wonder if that's the reason for your problem.

Comment: yeah, i was hoping that would be the case but I am getting blanks for all my scraping points after i change the driver source

Comment: it is working when the button is set to today and tomorrow bizarrely but only after human interaction changing it on the automated chromeweb

Comment: i added a refresh to the selenium prior to adding the driver source and it seems to have worked.